# Terraform Module for Azure APIM Associate Operation ID with Policies when import

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure

When importing a yaml/json file via terraform azurerm_api_management_api. Is there anyway to reference the operation_id when associating a operation without hardcoding it?

I don't think there is a suitable solution. I could decode the yaml file, I still have to reference the array by key/index. If I used lookup or looped an array, I might aswell add the policy to all apis level, the only advantage is I could just target gets;

similar to..
https://github.com/mikamakusa/terraform/blob/a6959c416104264e828281600bce1ac95e19629c/modules/Azure/APIManagement/api_operation/main.tf

Could I create a folder with files which containing the xml, with the file name as the operation id and the xml , then I could loop through the files creating the operation policies

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "api" {
  name                = local.api_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  api_management_name = var.api_management_name
  revision            = "1"
  service_url         = "https://www.google.com"
  path                = "terraform/test"
  subscription_required = true
  version_set_id      = data.azurerm_api_management_api_version_set.api_version_set.id
  protocols           = ["https"]

  import {
    content_format = "openapi"
    content_value  = file("${path.module}/demoapi.yaml")
  }
}

# unfortunately have to reference the import operations
module "demooperationpolicy" {
    source = "../../apioperationpolicies/demopolicy"
    api_name = azurerm_api_management_api.api.name
    api_management_name = var.api_management_name
    resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
    api_operation_id        =  **"user-get"**
}
```

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Demo-Terraform v1.0
  description: ''
  version: v1.0
servers:
  - url: 'https://gateway-dev.apis.uniper.energy/terraform/test/v1.0'
paths:
  /value:
    get:
      summary: Get User Operation
      description: Get User Operation
      operationId: user-get
      responses:
        '200':
          description: value
    post:
      summary: Post User Operation
      description: Post User Operation
      operationId: user-post
      responses:
        '200':
          description: value          
    delete:
      summary: Delete User Operation
      description: Delete User Operation
      operationId: user-delete
      responses:
        '200':
          description: value
components:
  securitySchemes:
    apiKeyHeader:
      type: apiKey
      name: Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key
      in: header
    apiKeyQuery:
      type: apiKey
      name: >-
        MUST-NOT-BE-USED-DUE-TO-SECURITY-RISK-CHANGES-TO-BE-AUDITED-8b9e9ebb68f24225
      in: query
security:
  - apiKeyHeader: []
  - apiKeyQuery: []
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with the following solution, xml files using the operation-id as the name, please let me know if there's a better solutions or anything to refined this process

operation policy module

```
variable "api_name" {}
variable "api_management_name" {}
variable "resource_group_name" {}
#variable "api_operation_id" {}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation_policy" "policy" {
  for_each = fileset(path.module, "/*.xml")
  api_name            = var.api_name
  api_management_name = var.api_management_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
# operation_id        = var.api_operation_id
  operation_id        = split(".",each.value)[0]

# this could come from a file
  xml_content = file("${path.module}/${each.value}")
#   xml_content = <<XML
# <policies>
#   <inbound>
#     <find-and-replace from="xyz" to="abc" />
#   </inbound>
# </policies>
# XML
}
```

template file named for example, user-post.xml and user-get.xml

```
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <find-and-replace from="rst" to="ghi" />
  </inbound>
</policies>
```